# How to configure and control mangling of module names in webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

**Background:**

A is an Angular shell with top and left nav. We have multiple apps B, C, D, etc built with different technologies which we want to load into the shell.

For example, B is Angular app whose feature modules will be lazy loaded into the shell, C is an old Dojo app whose features will be loaded into an iframe in the shell and D is a react app whose feature modules will be wrapped in an Angular component and loaded into the shell.

These apps are developed by different teams, hosted at different domains and they have their own release cycles. The shell A is being built in such a way that when an app wants to release an update, the shell doesn't have to be deployed again.

**Lazy Load Workflow:**

I am trying to lazy load a feature module built by Angular app B and hosted at a remote URL into the Angular shell A. Below is the workflow I am trying to achieve:

1. User clicks on link B in the shell.
2. An API call is made to get the list of features under B (B1, B2, B3, etc) and routes are pushed dynamically to the angular router for each feature.
3. User navigates to the feature B1 route in the shell.
4. The dependencies of B1 and B1's chunk file are fetched from a remote location and lazy loaded into the shell.

**Problem:**

Both shell A and app B have identical webpack configurations.

Shell A has unmangled module names as seen in image below.
[image]

Whereas app B has mangled module names as seen below with some modules removed by tree shaking I guess.
[image]

I will be able to lazy load feature module from app B into shell A if I can generate unmangled output in both projects, which is more reliable. Is there option in webpack that I can set to achieve this? If not, which part of webpack code is responsible for this, so that I can take a look and create a feature request maybe?

I use Webpack version 2.4.1, Angular CLI 1.1.1 and Angular 4.2.6.